# How can I define multiple sessionfactory instances in Spring?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I would like to have multiple Hibernate SessionFactories in a spring application, all of them with identical configurations except for the DataSource.  Ideally, I would acquire a particular SessionFactory by name.  I need to be able to do this based on runtime state, and it isn't possible to determine which session factories I will need at application startup time.  Basically, I need a SessionFactoryTemplate or something like it.

Is this possible?  How do I go about doing it?

Comment: Perhaps change your question to "How can I define and dynamically switch between multiple SessionFactory instances at runtime using Spring?" 
This better reflects your question (would edit, don't have enough points yet).

Answer (score 3):

You might define an abstract bean and use bean inheritance. This means you'll have a bean definition that works as a template and you may have multiple beans just copying the attributes set by the parent bean.

Here's an example:

```
<bean id="abstractSessionFactory" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingResources">
      <list>
        <value>product.hbm.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
      </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory" parent="abstractSessionFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory2" parent="abstractSessionFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource2"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

Using the attribute 'abstract' you ensure that bean won't be instantiated and it will be used just as a template.

More info here: [link text](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need multiple SessionFactories? If all the mappings/configurations are the same and you just have multiple identical databases (e.g. in a multi-tenant app?), then how about having a single SessionFactory that connects to a DataSource which dynamically supplies the appropriate database connection?

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120007/multiple-session-factories-under-spring-hibernate/120665#120665) for more details:

And [this blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) on Dynamic DataSource Routing in Spring.

Comment: Hi. The mappings are the same but it points to different schema/Database.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your current bean definition looks like now, but wouldn't you just ... define a second SessionFactory?

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory1" 
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource1"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
      <list>
        <value>product.hbm.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
      </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory2"
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource2"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

You could then simply just wire your DAOs up with one sessionFactory vs the other:

```
<bean id="myProductDao" class="product.ProductDaoImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myCompanyDao" class="product.ProductDaoImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory2"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I've clarified my description to explain why it's not the right answer.  Thanks, though!

Comment: Hi was thinking of this but how would you instantiate the different sessionfactories.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an easy solution for your problem using Spring.

However, you could be able to use Hibernate Interceptors, provided that your particular databases/data-sources can be reached through one master/admin database connection. [This blog post](http://www.alvinsingh.org/blog/2008/06/hibernate-dynamic-table-routing/) explains how in detail, but the gist of it is to dynamically replace table names in SQL statements that Hibernate generates, with qualified names identifying different databases. This is relatively easy to understand and maintain, and works well in my company's multi-tenant set-up.

Apart from that, you can try writing your own `TransactionManager`, using the `HibernateTransactionManager` as a starting point, adding support for working with multiple session factories. However, this would mean you having to really dive into Spring ORM support internals, and that is something I tried, but then scrapped in favor of the first approach. I'm sure it can be done with moderate effort, but the previous solution was already doing the job for us.